# Filter array of nested object using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to filter specific object using nested object element this

```json
"token": "4f1f17f6503e4c5a3a269ecf93d6c92d"
```

This my data:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "test",
    token: {
      expiryTime: "2021-09-24T12:27:30.654Z",
      purpose: "ForgotPassword3",
      token: "4f1f17f6503e4c5a3a269ecf93d6c92d",
    },
    user_id: "acaacc940c9ebfe798dee68acf5c",
    zipcode: "",
  },
  {
    name: "df ",
    token: null,
    user_id: "e0efe9810ca289ccd590bce48051",
    zipcode: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Io",
    phone: "88888888",
    state: "NY",
    token: null,
    user_id: "c88ce38d0c86f786c3a4b0f9f967",
    zipcode: "13201",
  },
];
```

Expected output is:
Data array inside the first object of token using filter object. Below given expected out.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "test",
    token: {
      expiryTime: "2021-09-24T12:27:30.654Z",
      purpose: "ForgotPassword3",
      token: "4f1f17f6503e4c5a3a269ecf93d6c92d",
    },
    user_id: "acaacc940c9ebfe798dee68acf5c",
    zipcode: "",
  },
];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. You are expected to invest your best effort to solve the problem by yourself first. Then, if you fail, search the web for why it might fail. If you've done all that and still didn't succeed, come back here, show your best attempt, explain how it fails and what you expect instead.

Comment: wait i ll share my code..

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: @gowdham looks like you haven't shared your code yet. Please do share your code

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific object, you could use `find` instead of filter. find will return the first element which verifies the condition specified to the find method where as the `filter` method is used to filters all the elements and returns all the element that matches the condition withing an array.

- *You need to add the optional chaining `?.` because the token object might be null like you have in some of your data
  here both examples:

```js
const data = [
  {
    
    "name": "test",
    "token": {
      "expiryTime": "2021-09-24T12:27:30.654Z",
      "purpose": "ForgotPassword3",
      "token": "4f1f17f6503e4c5a3a269ecf93d6c92d"
    },
    "user_id": "acaacc940c9ebfe798dee68acf5c",
    "zipcode": ""
  },
  {
    
    "name": "df ",
    "token": null,
    "user_id": "e0efe9810ca289ccd590bce48051",
    "zipcode": ""
  },
  {
    
    "name": "Io",
    "phone": "88888888",
    "state": "NY",
    "token": null,
    "user_id": "c88ce38d0c86f786c3a4b0f9f967",
    "zipcode": "13201"
  }
]

const resFilter = data.filter(x => x.token?.token === "4f1f17f6503e4c5a3a269ecf93d6c92d");

console.log(resFilter);

const resObj = data.find(x => x.token?.token === "4f1f17f6503e4c5a3a269ecf93d6c92d");

console.log(resObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use the following code
const finded = data.filter(user => user?.token?.token ==="value"})
console.log(finded);

Comment: Please don't reward askers that don't show the slightest research effort by answering.